# How to extend OrderedDict with defaultdict behavior

Tags: python, data-structures, ordereddictionary, defaultdict, dictionary-missing

I have a list of `OrderedDict` objects.  I would like to combine all of them together and then sort them by the fruit attribute in each of them. I have been trying to combine and sort them using `defaultdict` using the code below:

```
super_dict_apple = defaultdict(list)
super_dict_orange = defaultdict(list)
super_dict_no_fruit = defaultdict(list)


for d in dict:
        if 'fruit' not in d:
            for k, v in d.iteritems():
                super_dict_no_fruit[k].append(v)
        elif d['fruit'] == 'Apple':
            for k, v in d.iteritems():
                super_dict_apple[k].append(v)
        elif d['fruit'] == 'orange':
            for k, v in d.iteritems():
                super_dict_orange[k].append(v)
```

With this I get one key and all the associated values, but I lose the original order. So I tried to do it with an `OrderedDict`, but I cannot get it to work. This is what I tried:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

order_dict_no_fruit = OrderedDict()
order_dict_apple = OrderedDict()
order_dict_orange = OrderedDict()

for d in dict:
        if 'fruit' not in d:
            for k, v in d.iteritems():
                order_dict_no_fruit[k].append(v)
        elif d['fruit'] == 'Apple':
            for k, v in d.iteritems():
                order_dict_apple[k].append(v)
        elif d['fruit'] == 'orange':
            for k, v in d.iteritems():
                order_dict_orange[k].append(v)
```

My main goal is to keep the original order of the dictionaries but combine them into three different `OrderedDict` objects based on the fruit keys.

Comment: **How does it not work**. You should always be able to describe that in detail.

Comment: Please show an example of what you're getting and another example of what you expect.

Comment: Likely, it doesn't work because an `OrderedDict` is not a `defaultdict` so it doesn't automatically set a default value when accessing. If only there were `dict` method that *setdefault*...DOTDOT

Comment: Mention input, output you are getting and expected output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of a regular *OrderedDict*, try a subclass that adds in *defaultdict* behavior:

```
class OrderedDictWithDefaultList(OrderedDict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = list()
        self[key] = value
        return value
```

Comment: 'TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__''

Comment: You've got an error elsewhere in your code.  Perhaps you left off the parentheses off when instantiating the dictionaries.  It should be ``super_dict_apple = OrderedDictWithDefaultList()`` instead of  ``super_dict_apple = OrderedDictWithDefaultList``.