# Python Counter with defaultdict(int) behaviour

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, multiple-inheritance, toolz

Consider the following piece of code:

```
from collections import Counter
from cytoolz import merge_with

my_list = ["a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "d", "b"]
my_dict = {"a" : "blue", "b" : "green", "c" : "yellow", "d" : "red", "e" : "black"}

pair_dict = merge_with(tuple, my_dict, Counter(my_list))
```

I obtain the following `pair_dict`:

```
{'a': ('blue', 3),
 'b': ('green', 2),
 'c': ('yellow', 1),
 'd': ('red', 1),
 'e': ('black',)}
```

In my real case application I need the values in my `pair_dict` to be pairs, so `pair_dict["e"]` should be `('black', 0)`.

It would be very convenient if I could have **a class that extends `Counter` with the nice behaviour of a `defaultdict(int)`**.

Is this easily done?

I naïvely tried the following:

```
class DefaultCounter(defaultdict, Counter):
    pass

pair_dict = merge_with(tuple, my_dict, DefaultCounter(my_list))
```

But I get `TypeError: first argument must be callable or None`. I guess this is due to the fact that `defaultdict` expects a factory function.

So I tried the following:

```
pair_dict = merge_with(tuple, my_dict, DefaultCounter(int, my_list))
```

This results in `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`.

I also tried `class DefaultCounter(Counter, defaultdict)` but this does not have the desired effect: `pair_dict["e"]` is still `('black',)`.

Probably something else should be done in the definition of the class.

So I tried to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42404907/1878788):

```
class DefaultCounter(Counter):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = 0
        return 0
```

But this also doesn't have the desired effect (`pair_dict["e"]` still misses a second element).

---

#### Edit: `Counter` already behaves as `defaultdict(int)`, but `merge_with` does not trigger this behaviour.

As suggested in the comments, a `Counter` already has the desired behaviour:

```
my_counts = Counter(my_list)
assert my_counts["e"] == 0
```

The issue may actually lie in the way `merge_with` works: It doesn't trigger the desired `defaultdict` behaviour.

This is verified by the following test using a `defaultdict` instead of a `Counter`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_counts = defaultdict(int)
for letter in my_list:
    my_counts[letter] += 1
pair_dict = merge_with(tuple, my_dict, my_counts)
assert pair_dict["e"] == ('black',)
```

One must therefore ensure that all keys have been created in the `Counter` before merging with the other dict, for instance using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47396625/1878788).

Comment: `Counter` already exhibits that behaviour.  Try `Counter('')['a']`.  I suspect the problem is that `merge_with` is checking something like `key in d` and so is never trying `Counter(myList)['e']` to get that zero value.  Try to write a different function to replace `tuple` that will fill in mizzing values.  Or you might be able to write a `Counter` subclass that overwrite `__contains__` to return `True` for everything

Comment: Very relevant comment, @PatrickHaugh. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47396625/1878788) with the use of `merge_with`, I came up with the following solution:

```
from collections import Counter
from cytoolz import merge_with

my_list = ["a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "d", "b"]
my_dict = {
    "a" : "blue", "b" : "green", "c" : "yellow", "d" : "red", "e" : "black"}
my_counts = Counter(my_dict.keys()).update(my_list)
pair_dict = merge_with(
    tuple, my_dict,
    {k : v - 1 for (k, v) in my_counter.items()})
assert pair_dict["e"] == ('black', 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not what you asked for, but 1 option would be to initialise a `Counter` with the `dict` keys and then update it with the `list` and finally use a `dict` comprehension to get your desired output:

```
>>> c = Counter(my_dict.keys())
>>> c.update(my_list)
>>> {k:(my_dict[k],v-1) for k,v in c.items()}
{'a': ('blue', 3), 'b': ('green', 2), 'c': ('yellow', 1), 'd': ('red', 1), 'e': ('black', 0)}
```

Comment: This works, and I upvoted despite not being exactly what I asked for. Strangely, someone downvoted without leaving any comments. What is the issue with this approach? Currently, none of the other answers is exactly what I asked for either, and they did not get downvoted.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why it was downvoted,  an alternative would be `c = Counter(); for k in my_dict: c[k] = 0` and then update without the need for subtracting 1

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but some other ways to approach this porblem. `join`:

```
from toolz import first, join

{k: (v, c) for (_, c), (k, v) in join(
    leftkey=first, leftseq=Counter(my_list).items(), 
    rightkey=first, rightseq=my_dict.items(),
    left_default=(None, 0))}
```

and `merge_with`:

```
from toolz import *

merge_with(
    tuple, 
    my_dict, 
    reduce(
        lambda acc, x: update_in(acc, x, identity, 0),
        my_dict.keys(), 
        Counter(my_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary comprehension should do similar to list comprehension.

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "d", "b"]
my_dict = {"a" : "blue", "b" : "green",
           "c" : "yellow", "d" : "red", "e" : "black"}

res={key:(my_dict[k], my_list.count(k)) for k in my_dict}
res

# {'a': ('blue', 3), 'b': ('green', 2), 'c': ('yellow', 1),
#  'd': ('red', 1), 'e': ('black', 0)}
```